# Java 8 Method expression is giving compilation error

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am new to Java 8 (Lambda Expression). The following piece of code prints all the directories at the path indicated by the variable "file".

```
File file = new File("/vssexclude/Test/workspace/Test");

File[] names = file.listFiles(fileName -> fileName.isDirectory());

for (File name : names) {
    System.out.println(name.toString());
}
```

But, when I try to replace the lambda expression with method expression, eclipse is giving compilation error:

```
File[] names = file.listFiles(File::isDirectory());
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I would also add that while the functionality may be the same, you should really use the new `Path` class instead of `File` from Java 7 on. Mostly it works the same, but it is better suited for directory probing, name concatenating, hard and soft links etc. See [`Files.newDirectoryStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.DirectoryStream.Filter%29).

Comment: Thanks, let me try that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis :

```
File[] names = file.listFiles(File::isDirectory);
```

When you want to refer to an instance method of an object of a particular type, the syntax to use is :

```
ContainingType::methodName
```

This is described in more details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: Ha ha ha! Thanks for the answer. Made a mistake like a kid. :-)

Comment: I checked the Java documentation also, but somehow missed the parenthesis thing.